# Unbounded git bisect

Tags: git, git-bisect

Is it possible to use git bisect with one of the bounds unspecified. For example if I discover something broken on HEAD but I suspect it worked *at some point* in the past, is there a way to tell git "try one commit ago, if that doesn't work try two commits ago, then four, then eight, etc."?

Answer (score 3):

Not really; `git-bisect` operates on a fixed range of commits, so you need to give it two boundaries up front.

If you aren't sure how far back in history the *good* commit is, your best bet is to start with a larger range than what you consider likely. For example, if you suspect that things were good some time last week, set the start commit to two weeks ago.

After all, going through a large number of commits with [as few steps as possible](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#_binary_search) is what `git-bisect` does best.

Comment: Yeah I guess my problem is that "a larger range than I consider likely" is an unknown, so I end up checking... I don't know 10 commits back, then 20, and then.. "hey maybe git bisect could do this for me!".